# How do I find the distance from a point to a plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am trying to find the distance from point $(8, 0, -6)$ and plane $x+y+z = 6$. I tried solving it but I am still getting it wrong. Can anyone help me on this? Any help I would very much appreciate.

The following is my work:

$$d = \sqrt{(x-8)^2 + (y-0)^2 + (z+6)^2}$$

since $x+y+z = 6$, $z = 6-x-y$, so

\begin{align*}
d &= \sqrt{(x-8)^2 + (y-0)^2 + (-x-y+12)^2} \\
d^2 &= (x-8)^2 + (y-0)^2 + (-x-y)^2
\end{align*}

Find partial derivative $f_x$ and $f_y$ and critical points

\begin{align*}
f_x &= 2(x-8) + 2(-x-y+12) \\
&= 24-2y \quad (\text{set }= 0) \\
&= \text{critical point }y = 4 \\
f_y &= 2y + 2(-x-y+12) \\
&= 24 - 2x \quad (\text{set }= 0) \\
&= \text{critical point }x = 12 \\
\end{align*}

Plug in $x = 12$ and $y = 4$ to original equation

$$d = \sqrt{(x - 8)^2 + (4)^2 + (-12-4+12)^2} = \sqrt{48}$$

Comment: How did the $6$ become the $12$?

Comment: because z = - x - y + 6. So since I plug in (z + 6)^2 in the distance formula, it becomes (-x - y + 12)^2

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is a good one, and in fact can lead to the general formula mentioned in the other answers.

You just made a few mistakes in your calculation.

For example, you say that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ (x-8)^2+y^2+(-x-y+12)^2 \right]$ is $2(x-8)+2(-x-y+12)$, when really it is $2(x-8)-2(-x-y-12)$.  You forgot the chain rule.

You make a similar chain rule mistake when calculating the partial derivative with respect to $y$.

I think if you fix these, you should be able to finish your calculation the way you started it.

Note to other posters:  I think it is generally of greater pedagogical value to help a student realize how to fix their own reasoning, rather than supplying them with a totally different method.  Our primary aim should be to empower students to realize that they have the power to think through these things logically and creatively.

Comment: +1 for fixing the error in the - otherwise correct - OP's solution.

Answer (score 2):

The distance formula is $$D=\frac{|ax_0+by_0 +cz_0-d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt3}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The closest distance will be along a line perpendicular to the plane or parallel to $(1,1,1)$. Since $8+0+-6=2$ we must add $\frac{4}{3}$ to each component so that $x+y+z$ now equals $6$. Therefore, the distance is $|(\frac{4}{3}, \frac{4}{3}, \frac{4}{3})|=\sqrt{3\frac{16}{9}}=\sqrt{\frac{16}{3}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$

Answer (score 1):

It's $$\frac{|8+0-6-6|}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2+1^2}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt3}.$$
I used the following formula.

The distance from the point $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ to the plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ it's
$$\frac{|ax_1+by_1+cz_1+d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}.$$

Also, we can end your way.

Indeed, by C-S
$$\sqrt{(x-8)^2+y^2+(z+6)^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\sqrt{(1^2+1^2+1^2)((x-8)^2+y^2+(z+6)^2)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\sqrt{(x-8+y+z+6)^2}=\frac{4}{\sqrt3}$$ and we got the distance again.

Comment: thank you very much! this I smuch quicker than what I am being told to do

Answer (score 1):

Option:

Normal of the plane: $(1,1,1)$,

Normalized(i.e of unit length): $(1/√3)(1,1,1)$

Line through $(8,0,-6)$:

$\vec r= (8,0,-6)+t (1/√3)(1,1,1)$.

Determine $t$ when line intersects plane:

$(8+t/√3)+t/√3+(-6+t/√3)=6;$

$3(t/√3)=4$;

$t= 4/√3.$

Distance = $4/√3$ (Why?).

Comment: Very nice application of vector algebra (+1). The answer could be improved by *explicitly* citing that the coefficients of the variables in the plane equations are the component of a vector orthogonal to the plane. And also answering the last "why?" could improve it. The OP (or other people reading the answer) might not be aware of this application of vector algebra. This answer would need a nice drawing to be great!

Comment: Lorenzo.Thanks.If you feel any edits would be in place, feel free. This answer is an option, a bit of a different approach ,not just calculating a root, etc.Thank you again for your kind words.Greetings, Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a line from your point to the plane and then find the length of its projection onto the unit normal vector to the plane.